# Need of Atharvashikha Upanishad in English Translation with Sanskrit Sloka?

Tags: scripture, upanishads, translation-request, translation

Where can I get Atharvashikha Upanishad in English Translation with Sanskrit Shloka in pdf form? Namah Shivay

Answer (score 1):

1.[Atharvashikha Upanishad Sanskrit Shlokas](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/atharvashikha.html)

2.[Atharvashika Upanishad English Translation by P.R.Ramchander](https://cloudup.com/cyx6zGblpIg)

(P.S. The translation begins after the Shanti Mantra)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

https://cloudup.com/cyx6zGblpIg This site has both, Sanskrit and English translation. Check the three entries on the left side.